# Access violation executing location - GetFileAttributesA

Tags: c, winapi

I am having a peculiar problem with GetFileAttributedA on Windows 8.1 x64 on VS2012. The functions runs fine, but once in a while the statement crashes with

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000003 in MyService.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000003.

Here is the pseudo code.

```
char    szItemAbsPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD   rc = 0;
DWORD   dwFileAttribute = 0;

memset(szItemAbsPath, '\0', sizeof(szItemAbsPath));
sprintf(szItemAbsPath, "%s%s%s", "D:\\Root", FILE_SEPARATOR_STR, "temp.txt");

// check item type
dwFileAttribute = GetFileAttributesA(szItemAbsPath); //this is where program crashes
if (dwFileAttribute == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
    rc = GetLastError();
        return rc;
}

if (dwFileAttribute & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{
    // this is a dir
}
```

I basically want to check if a given item is a file or folder. This problem is sometimes observed in 32bit builds too.

### Edited:

MiniDump

```
Dump Summary
------------
Dump File:  MyDesktopService.dmp : C:\Users\anand\Desktop\MyDesktopService.dmp
Last Write Time:    09-04-2014 17:34:24
Process Name:   MyDesktopService.exe : D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\MyDesktopService.exe
Process Architecture:   x86
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information:  The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information:   Present

System Information
------------------
OS Version: 6.2.9200
CLR Version(s): 

Modules
-------
Module Name Module Path Module Version
----------- ----------- --------------
MyDesktopService.exe    D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\MyDesktopService.exe 0.0.0.0
ntdll.dll   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll   6.3.9600.16502
kernel32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll    6.3.9600.16520
KERNELBASE.dll  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll  6.3.9600.16496
MSVCR110D.dll   D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\MSVCR110D.dll    11.0.51106.1
MyDesktop.dll   D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\MyDesktop.dll    0.0.0.0
libeay32.dll    D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\libeay32.dll 1.0.1.6
wtsapi32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll    6.3.9600.16384
userenv.dll C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll 6.3.9600.16384
advapi32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll    6.3.9600.16384
ws2_32.dll  C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll  6.3.9600.16384
libcurl_debug.dll   D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\libcurl_debug.dll    7.34.0.0
jansson.dll D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\jansson.dll  0.0.0.0
gdi32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll   6.3.9600.16421
user32.dll  C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll  6.3.9600.16441
msvcr110.dll    C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110.dll    11.0.51106.1
msvcrt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll  7.0.9600.16384
rpcrt4.dll  C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll  6.3.9600.16384
profapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll 6.3.9600.16384
sechost.dll C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll 6.3.9600.16384
nsi.dll C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll 6.3.9600.16384
Wldap32.dll C:\Windows\System32\Wldap32.dll 6.3.9600.16384
normaliz.dll    C:\Windows\System32\normaliz.dll    6.3.9600.16384
ssleay32.dll    D:\Works\My\My_Recovered_from_SVN_Crash\MyVS2012\NSLib\ssleay32.dll 1.0.1.6
sspicli.dll C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll 6.3.9600.16408
CRYPTBASE.dll   C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll   6.3.9600.16384
bcryptPrimitives.dll    C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll    6.3.9600.16384
winsta.dll  C:\Windows\System32\winsta.dll  6.3.9600.16384
IPHLPAPI.DLL    C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL    6.3.9600.16384
winnsi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll  6.3.9600.16384
dhcpcsvc6.DLL   C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL   6.3.9600.16384
dhcpcsvc.dll    C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll    6.3.9600.16384
mswsock.dll C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll 6.3.9600.16384
dnsapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll  6.3.9600.16423
rasadhlp.dll    C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll    6.3.9600.16384
NapiNSP.dll C:\Windows\System32\NapiNSP.dll 6.3.9600.16384
pnrpnsp.dll C:\Windows\System32\pnrpnsp.dll 6.3.9600.16384
nlaapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll  6.3.9600.16384
winrnr.dll  C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll  6.3.9600.16384
wshbth.dll  C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll  6.3.9600.16384
cryptsp.dll C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll 6.3.9600.16384
rsaenh.dll  C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll  6.3.9600.16384
bcrypt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll  6.3.9600.16384
```

### Call Stack:

```
    00000003()  Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  
>   MyDesktop.dll!HandleModifyEvent(...) Line 159   C
    MyDesktop.dll!ProcessFSEvent(...) Line 79   C
    MyDesktop.dll!NSFileSysEventProcessor(void * lpParam=0x01adf324) Line 59    C
    MyDesktop.dll!thread_first_breath(sThrdInfo * psParam=0x009d2848) Line 1119 C
    msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 354 C
    msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd=0x009ff308) Line 337    C
    kernel32.dll!7790495d() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77b498ee()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77b498c4()    Unknown
```

Comment: Are you always using fixed string for filename? Make sure `sprintf` do not go beyond `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: Don't show pseudo code, show the real code.

Comment: BTW the `memset` before `sprintf` is not needed, `sprintf` takes care of terminating the generated string with '\0'.

Comment: Are you sure the program crashes **actually** during the call of `GetFileAttributesA` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes I am pretty sure. It crashes on 'GetFileAttributesA'. I have observed this many times.

Comment: The real program is reading items from linked list and creating the 'szItemAbsPath' and passing to 'GetFileAttributesA'. Once i detect it as a file i upload it to a server.

Comment: What is `FILE_SEPARATOR_STR`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan #define FILE_SEPARATOR_STR "\\"

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere in your code. You probably overwrite some memory you shouldn't or you continue to used previously freed memory and that leads to your crash later on. Does it also crash in debug builds ?$

Comment: buffer overflows can have effects at a seemingly completely unrelated point in code

Comment: Am I the only one that sees the irony of `sprintf(szItemAbsPath, "%s%s%s", "D:\\Root", FILE_SEPARATOR_STR, "temp.txt");`, where (a) the "abstracted" separator is also hard-coded in the first part of the filename `"D:\\Root"`, and (b) the entire thing could be in an initializer regardless.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, it crashes on debug builds too.

Comment: @Anand, well that's good news. Then it shouldn't be too difficult to find out what's going on. Edit your question and include the stack dump.

Comment: The minidump is not useful, we need the **stackdump**.

Comment: @MichaelWalz. Sorry for my ignorance. Do you mean call stack ? or should i use MiniDumpWriteDump to generate the dump ?

Comment: Run your debug build from Visual Studio and once it has crashed use the Debug->Windows->Call stack command.

Comment: The stackdump shows that something goes terribly wrong in a function called by `HandleModifyEvent(...)`. You have to debug this. It's impossible for us to do more without a complete insight into your project. I'm aware that finding this problem is probably not easy. It is certainly some buffer overflow or some memory corruption somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Within reasonable assumptions, this code cannot generate this error. The size of this array is one short, but it's still 260 in length which is plenty for the example.

An access violation of this kind is strongly suggestive of a wild store. One or more of the pointer arguments to the function has been corrupted and triggers an access violation when used.

---

As pointed out in a comment, access violations of the nature of "at location 0x000000nn" strongly indicate a NULL pointer dereference to a structure or class member that is nn bytes offset from the beginning of the object. Sometimes it will be a pointer that has had a small integer stored into it. Sometimes it will be a null that has been incremented. All strongly suggestive of data getting overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Further, access violations of the nature of "at location 0x000000nn" strongly indicate a NULL pointer dereference to a structure or class member that is `nn` bytes offset from the beginning of the structure. More often than not, that is eventually where the debugger takes you. In this case, it looks like a *code* pointer, which tells me someone is possibly blasting over a vtable.